# How can i disable files or folders in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Most of the times i copy a file for backup before changing it, i do this because my team might need a new release and i simply rename the previos file, create a new `Build` with the file, and then i rename the files again and continue my own work on the new version of the file, this works great, but the problem lies in when i try to search for a file using `ctrl + e`, sometimes i go to an old version of a file by mistake or i find the old (renamed) file first!, i wish this program just had an easy disable file or folder option, is there a way to accomplish this?, maybe a hidden setting or an extension i don't know about ?
**So my final goal is to right click on a folder or file and simply click disable so it doesn't show up in any search tool or replace or ...**

I should mention `visual studio` has something similar where you can disable a file so its ignored when you compile

Comment: Why don't you use a version control software?

Answer (score 1):

You need version control. I'd recommend [git](https://git-scm.com/).

- The problem you've described doesn't exist, because no two copies of a file exist simultaneously. If you want to switch to a different version, you issue appropriate git command (or use IDE's integration) and you get the new version in a fraction of second.
- Versioning is easy, git does it for you. You don't have to maintain multiple copies of the source tree by hand.
- When you have two versions of project that branched off in different directions, you can request git to merge one into the other. Most of the time it happens automatically and it even resolves some conflicts for you.
- Hundreds of other advantages.

Here are [some learning resources](https://try.github.io/).

Comment: I know Visual Studio 2019 supports only searching through files added to the solution itself.  This avoids finding results within text-based data files that the program might use.  However, that requires specific actions, when a search is performed to verify Visual Studio is only looking at files added to the solution itself.  Of course, I agree, that the solution to the problem described is indeed source control.